# Given N and d, what's the maximal line segments with length d in plane with N points.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Given $N$ and $d$, what's the maximal number of line segments of length $d$ in plane with $N$ points.

I have a hypothesis, it is $\Theta(N)$, but I can't figure out, how to prove or contradict it.

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

Let's have result $f(N)$. $f(N)\in\Theta(N)$ means that there are $c_1, c_2, k\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c_1 N \leq f(N)\leq c_2 N$ for every $N>k$.

I would be happy with even with just asymtotic solution.

Comment: What is $\Theta(N)$?

Comment: @Jens Can you understand it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By rescaling, you may as well assume $d=1$.  In this form this is an old open problem known as the "Erdős Unit Distance Problem".  Erdős [showed in 1946](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1946-03.pdf) that the maximum is at least $n^{1+c/\log \log n}$ (in particular, that it's not linear), but the corresponding best known upper bound is only on the order of $n^{4/3}$.   Szemerédi (who proved this upper bound together with Spencer and Trotter) has a [recent survey](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-32162-2_15) of work on the problem.